# Shortcut for mapping a Stream to a Map with an identity key

Tags: java, java-stream

Consider the following example code processing a list of strings by mapping each string to its length and printing each mapping entry

```
package com.dbenergie.ndm.bnb.business;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World", "!");

        // 1
        final Map<String, Integer> stringCharacterCountMapping = strings.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), String::length));

        stringCharacterCountMapping.entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Now, what I personally find rather messy or boilerplate-ish is the explicit mapping of each stream entry as the key of the map using `Function.identity()` (at 1) but every mapping collector I found so far requires a key mapper - is there some collector I overlooked or do I have to define my own collector if I would need this? It would be quite handy to have something like

```
Collectors.toMap(String::length);
```

or similar. Any ideas?

Comment: `toMap` without defining the key mapping, is that what you mean?

Comment: `toMap` implicitely using the stream element as the key.

Comment: If see in the documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) , there are actually 3 Collectors.toMap method each with keyMapper as argument. So it is not possible without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There is no `toMap` method in the `Collectors` class that does not take a `keyMapper`.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) I suspect that this is because it can be quite ambiguous what that single argument you pass in maps to. The value or the key?

You can easily write such a collector yourself:

```
class MyCollectors {
    public static <K, U> Collector<K, ?, Map<K,U>> toMapWithValueWrapper(Function<? super K, ? extends U> valueMapper) {
        return Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), valueMapper);
    }
}
```

Notice the signature is a little different from `Collectors.toMap`. There are only 2 generic parameters. The original `Collectors.toMap` has 3 - `T` (the type we are collecting), `K` (the type of key) and `U` (the type of value). Since you are using the identity function for the key, the key will always have the same type as the type that we are collecting, so `T == K`. Therefore, we can eliminate `T`.

Edit:

As Holger suggested in the comments, we don't have to force `T == K` because `T` could be a subclass of `K` and you could still use the identity function to map from `T` to `K`. Therefore, you could use this:

```
class MyCollectors {
    public static <T extends K, K, U> Collector<T, ?, Map<K,U>> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper) {
        return Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), valueMapper);
    }
}
```

if you want to allow collecting to a map whose key type is a super class of the type you are collecting.

Comment: Looks exactly like the shortcut I implemented - sad to see that this use-case isn't present yet but good to see that this is achievable with quite a small amount of code.

Comment: We *can* eliminate `T`, but the question is whether we should. If we use `<T extends K>`, we allow collecting a stream of more specific elements into a map with a broader key type. It’s the same reason why we use `Function<? super K, ? extends U>` instead of `Function<K, U>`…